# Run mocha excluding paths

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I have this (in gulpfile.js):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var mocha = require("gulp-mocha");
gulp.task("test", function() {
    gulp
        .src(["./**/*_test.js", "!./node_modules/**/*.js"]);
});
```

and it works.

I want to replicate the same behavior, **excluding "node_modules" folder**, from mocha command, running *npm test* (in package.json):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha **\\*_test.js !./node_modules/**/*.js*",
}
```

and it doesn't work.

I'm using Windows.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by @thebearingedge, in the end **I put ALL the source files (with the relative test files) in a new "src" dir**.
In this way I can define the root for tests with a path that exclude by default the "node_modules" folder.

```
.
├── src  
    ├── fileA.js  
    ├── fileA_test.js  
    ├── fileB.js  
    ├── fileB_test.js  
├── node_modules
    ├── ...
```

I had to update the path in the package.json, gulpfile.js and in some batch files that I use as utilities.

Changes in *gulpfile.js*:

```
.src(["./src/**/*_test.js"]);
```

and in *package.json*:

```
"test": "mocha src\\**\\*_test.js",
```

Simple change and it works.

- I'm free to choose whatever naming conventions I like.
- Each test files remain close to the relative JS file.

Comment: It's a shame that you had to... it's quite a popular pattern to keep tests close to the logic under test  - I personally much prefer it.
An option that you could try is to suffix your files like so `testfile.spec.js` and just match all files that end with `.spec.js`. Maybe give it a whirl in your next project!

Comment: Why is it a shame? I just moved all the source files is a "src" folder. I haven't moved the test files, they stay close to their logic as before. I don't have to worry about naming convention conflict too (it was for "_test.js but another time could be .spec.js). In this way it is excluded any possible conflict with "node_modules" by default. The suggested solution (by @thebearingedge) was simple and effective.

Answer (score 31):

I was able to solve this using globbing patterns in the argument to `mocha`. Like you I didn't want to put all my tests under a single `tests` folder. I wanted them in the same directory as the class they were testing. My file structure looked like this:

```
project
|- lib
   |- class1.js
   |- class1.test.js
|- node_modules
   |- lots of stuff...
```

Running this from the `project` folder worked for me:

```
mocha './{,!(node_modules)/**}/*.test.js'
```

Which match any `*.test.js` file in the tree, so long is its path isn't rooted at `./node_modules/`.

This is an [online tool](http://www.globtester.com) for testing glob patterns that I found useful.

Comment: thanks, this one is only works for me, after several others trying.

Comment: What if `node_modules` may be anywhere in the path?

Comment: RIP online tool.

Comment: not sure if it is the same tool, but —> https://globster.xyz

Comment: @justin.m.chase mocha '\*\*/{,!(node_modules)/**}/*.test.js'

Answer (score 18):

You can exclude files in mocha by passing opts

```
mocha -h|grep -i exclude
    --exclude <file>                        a file or glob pattern to ignore (default: )

mocha --exclude **/*-.jest.js
```

Additionally, you can also create a `test/mocha.opts` file and add it there

```
# test/mocha.opts
--exclude **/*-test.jest.js
--require ./test/setup.js
```

If you want to exclude a particular file type you could do something like this

```
// test/setup.js
require.extensions['.graphql'] = function() {
  return null
}
```

This is useful when processing extensions with a module loader such as webpack that mocha does not understand.

Answer (score 11):

**For Windows users**
This script will run perfectly

```
 "test": "mocha \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\"",
```

I hope this will help.

cheers!

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the syntax in curly braces? Is it a regex? Or is it a special syntax for mocha command? What does the first comma mean?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a guru on mocha or ant-style pattern but maybe it isn't possible escluding specific path in the mocha command line.

You can put all your test files under a test folder, and set your package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./test/**/*_test.js"
}
```

You can also provide more than one starting folder:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./test/**/*_test.js ./another_test_folder/**/*_test.js"
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to put ALL my test files under a specific folder.
I decided to have a *_test.js file NEAR the files to test. I have many folders that contain test files. The problem is that I've added Unit.js package and it uses my same naming convention for test files (*_test.js) so, now, my mocha run captures this tests. I don't want to change my naming convention too. Thanks for the suggestion, it is good.

Comment: Do you at least have your project source in its own folder? That way, you could point mocha to `src/**/*_test.js` and keep test files near the source. Except really small modules with only 1 source file, putting js files in a dedicated directory like `src` or `lib` seems the common practice.

Comment: This would be the right answer if the question was : How can i re-arrange my entire project structure to run only certain tests?

Answer (score 5):

As of 2019 the modern way of [configuring Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs) under Node is via config file in your project root (e.g. via `.mocharc.js`).

Here is the example of the `.mocharc.js` that

- rederfines the default test directory (`spec` key) and
- excludes the example (or can be any experimental tests) from the overall suite (`exclude` key).

```
module.exports = {
    'spec': 'src/front/js/tests/**/*.spec.js',
    'exclude': 'src/front/js/tests/examples/*.spec.js',
    'reporter': 'dot'
};
```

As you may see there can be more options used in the config. In part they are just replicas of [Mocha CLI options](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage). Just look up ones what you like and try to use within `.mocharc.js` ([use camelCase](https://mochajs.org/#configuration-format) for dash-comprising CLI options). Or see [the config examples](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js).

Comment: This didn't work for me; Mocha ignored the `exclude`.  Also, per https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js, it's supposed to be `ignore`, not `exclude` (but neither one prevented Mocha from running my `node_modules` tests, so I had to go with the other answer).

Comment: @machineghost I see. The official [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage) says it is either `exclude` or `ignore`. I did not use mocha for a long time so I cannot confirm now it works as explained.

Answer (score 1):

I had a `spec` directory containing all my specs. Within that directory, I had several sub-directories, one of which was the `e2e` specs directory. In that scenario, I used the `mocha specs $(find specs -name '*.js' -not -path "specs/e2e/*")` command to run all my tests ignoring those within the `e2e` directory.

Comment: I prefer to avoid this way. I prefer to have my myfile_test.js close to the myfile.js file. In this way I try to "force" me (and the other) to create test files. It is also immediate to find files that are not tested. Is also more simple to rename/delete test files when the origin change. In practice I found this way more effective.