# How to avoid node_modules tests, e.g. json-schema-traverse?

Tags: json, mocha.js

I have 5 of my own tests, 2 passing, 4 failing (intentionally, as I make them pass).

But I also have 12 other `json-schema-traverse` tests and I'm not sure where they are coming from. I don't find files that have them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests selector in my npm `package.json` of

```
"test": "mocha **/*.spec.*"
```

picks up additional tests in `node_modules/`

I can avoid these tests in a node module by using `--exclude`, i.e.

```
mocha **/*.spec.js --exclude node_modules/**/*.spec.js
```

Another approache that avoids using exclude could change:

```
**/*.spec.*
```

to, for example

```
./*.spec.js ./test/*spec.js
```

Comment: Where did you look for those files? That happens because `json-schema-traverse` includes its `spec/` directory in the distributed package. An alternative solution would therefore be e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058896/3001761. But the information required to find the problem isn't in the question.